# Easiest way to include content from another site without using frames?

Tags: frameset

I want to setup a page for an upcoming project on my site. The problem is, this site doesn't have a lot of bandwidth. So I'm thinking to put the real data on the Amazon cloud, and use my site as just a placeholder.

Before, it was customary to do this with frames - I could create a very small page on my site, and pull the data from Amazon via a frame. However, this is ugly, antiquated, and probably doesn't look good on some mobile devices and so on.

What is the modern equivalent to this? I am looking for simple methods. It is imperative that the browsers pull the data page directly from Amazon, not through my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iframe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5) or [object](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#embedded-documents). See also the work in progress for [iframes in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html).

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with a site that pulls the content through iframes / objects / frames is that search engines will generally only find the content on the embedded page (with that URL) and not with your page's URL. If you don't need to be found in search engines, then that might be fine. If you do need to have that content be associated with your site in web-search, then you need to host the content directly on your site.

Comment: @JohnMueller Good point. I'm not worried about search engines. I only need to host the live data on the cloud during the experiment; after that, I will move it to my site.